# Internal SD periodically becomes inaccessible

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, internal-sd

I'm having an issue with my Samsung Galaxy S. My phone has trouble reading my internal SD card. When the problem occurs, I cannot take pictures, or even access the "My Files" folder.

When I check the settings in the SD card and phone storage area, everything is unavailable or greyed out. The phone is not USB mounted when this happens. A battery pull fixes the problem, but this seems unconventional. Also Kies does not work as well with my device.

Comment: That sounds much more like a hardware issue to me, personally. Have you taken it in to where you bought it and asked them to look at it?

Comment: not yet..before I take it to the store I wanted to know what you think guys?

Comment: Any results so far? It's almost a year gone. Maybe meanwhile you can answer the question yourself?

Comment: (for Izzy)If you want you can close this - I replace my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with my Ainol Novo 7 Crystal Quad Core and the solution was simple but took hours of research.
The internal SD partition that goes beyond the memory reserved for the OS and some apps may have become corrupted.
Go to the backup/reset tab in "settings" and click the erase SD card.
You will be told that you will lose all the information on it but you will only lose that which you cannot access anyway.
Erase the card.
Once it is erased, you will be able to mount it when you go to "storage" and you push the remount button.
Hope this of help and use to you. It worked for me.